# How to find the Serial Number for a Linux host using ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

So, I have looked high and low for an ansible "built-in" fact for a Linux server serial number, and it looks like it's not available without a custom dmidecode ansible module. Is this really the case? It seems strange to me that with the plethora of built-in ansible facts the serial number is not included.

```
$ /usr/bin/ansible --version
ansible 2.4.2.0
  config file = /home/user/.ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/user/.ansible/plugins/modules', 
u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Aug  9 2016, 06:11:56) [GCC 4.4.7 
20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described in the [Ansible documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/setup_module.html), gathering facts is done through the `setup` module.

To see all facts for all hosts defined in the Ansible inventory file:

```
ansible all -m setup
```

To see the serial number for a specific Linux host (myserver01) that exists in the inventory file:

```
ansible -b myserver01 -m setup -a 'filter=ansible_product_serial'
```

And for the same fact gathered from a host (myserver01) that is not in the inventory file:

```
ansible -b -i myserver01, all -m setup -a 'filter=ansible_product_serial'
```

Updated the response to incorporate @Henk's comments: the ansible command needs to run with `become` (`-b`) for getting the ansible_product_serial data. Add also `-K` if you are not using a passwordless privilege escalation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The 'ansible_product_serial' variable does not contain the serial number for the server. On both a virtual and physical server here is the output I see from running the setup module - "ansible_product_serial": "NA"

Comment: Fair is fair: Cristi is right, but you'll have to run the command as root so with  with "--become", so like `ansible -b -K -i inventory-file hostname.example.com -m setup -a 'filter=ansible_product_serial'`

Comment: @user3155618 Did you try running the command with `become`? I've tried on 2 separate machines running RHEL, a VM and a physical, I get the exact same output from running `/usr/sbin/dmidecode -s system-serial-number` directly on the machines or running from remote `ansible -b -K -i myserver01, all -m setup -a 'filter=ansible_product_serial'`

Comment: @Henk what made you change your mind and put an answer saying that you cannot get that from the ansible facts?

Comment: @CristiDascalu @user3155618 Well, you can ONLY get it from the facts when running your command with "become". As a regular user you are not allow to `cat /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/product_serial`. Maybe it works on your side because you enable `become=True` as a default in the configuration. In that way your answer was the first AND the right one.
I think at this time it would be more than fair if your answer is marked as the right one instead of mine, but it should include a mention of the "become".

Comment: Thank you so much Cristi, for your courteous correction of my previous comment. I tried using -b for become and it worked like a charm. Your answer is now the accepted answer. Thanks for your responses to @Henk